# Why is BeautifulSoup unable to retrieve og:image metadata while Facebook Sharing Debugger is able to do so?

Tags: image, beautifulsoup, facebook-opengraph, facebook-debugger

Here is my BeautifulSoup code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
html = requests.get("https://vt.tiktok.com/ZSLvos3x2/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

image = soup.find("meta",  {"property":"og:image"})
print(image)
```

The result's content is empty:

```
<meta content="" data-rh="true" property="og:image"/>
```

However, [Facebook's Sharing Debugger can read it](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fvt.tiktok.com%2FZSLvos3x2%2F):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/tos-maliva-p-0068/e025f28037a84ad4b86d9437ba70ad2d_1683178221~tplv-photomode-video-share-card:1200:630:20.jpeg?x-expires=1695362400&amp;x-signature=MNuRNoO2lAxX61zDfuqG5mKnI74%3D">
```

Some suggest that this is because it's a JS problem, however this doesn't explain why trying it multiple times will make it success:

```py
try = 1
not_get_data = True
while (try <= 5 and not_get_data):
    print('Try:', try)
    html = requests.get(url=url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Why is that?

Comment: `bs4` is just an HTML parser that can't run `JavaScript`. I don't know what Facebook Sharing Debugger is, but my guess is it *can* run `JS`.

Comment: the point is, some of the links return the results without problem. So I don't think it's the problem of running js

Answer (score 1):

The result's content is empty which means this content comes from JavaScript and you have to use Selenium or a similar browser automation Python library.
after getting the js content you can parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup then use regex for get og image url

**using regex**

```
og_image = re.find("og:image[^>]+content="([^"]+),soup)
print(og_image.group(1))
```

**full code:**

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://vt.tiktok.com/ZSLvos3x2/")
time.sleep(3) #here waiting three seconds 
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
og_image = re.find("og:image[^>]+content="([^"]+),soup)
print(og_image.group(1))
```

also u can use `image = soup.find("meta",  {"property":"og:image"})` instead of regex

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you check again?

Comment: @Ooker the solution will be same as I said if the content loading from js then you have to use Selenium or a similar browser automation Python library

Comment: I know. I just wonder why BS can still retrieve the content on the second or third try? I don't think the host changes the method the data is load from JS to pure HTML when the first request from the client fails